# Tradeoff between (op) amplifier voltage range and offset and settling

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, offset, rail-to-rail

I know that an amplifier (let's take an op-amp) can't swing rail-to-rail. The reason has to do with the load device. For example, in a normal common gate/common base amplifier, the load device causes a voltage drop. Usually we put a current source as a load and ideally a current source would give constant current even when the voltage drop across is reaches zero. However, practical current sources stop acting as current sources when the voltage drops below a certain threshold (VDsat for a MOSFET since the device is not in saturation any mode) and this is why the output can't swing rail-to-rail. The output starts to clip. If we still increase the input voltage, the output will be distorted.

Now let's assume an opamp, connected as voltage follower (buffer) which drives a lumped RC line:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSVekV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let's assume the amplifier is a as simple as (OTA):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUBgOT.png)</sup>

I was told the reason we cannot increase the voltage swing (in particular, can't reach ground) is that offsets become more severe and the settling deteriorates. I made the argument that rail-to-rail op-amps exist (hence no distortion) but was told that the tradeoff with settling and offset still exists.

I have a hard time seeing this. Can anyone help me to connect the dots? Based on first principles, how is the output voltage swing related to offset and settling performance?

Comment: With a current sink output, the low voltage cannot exceed the I*R=V level towards 0V in an AC coupled load or a LPF in your OTA.

Comment: Suppose the offset has magnitude one volt. Stick zero into (+) and the output will be -1 or +1. That might have an impact on your rail-to-rail debate. Suppose it takes time to settle (it always does.) Then you stick zero into (+) and the output will slew to match what it thinks (within offset error and gain) matches. That takes time and may be underdamped or overdamped (we don't know the compensation.) Again that may impact your conversation. This doesn't seem all that interesting, posed as it is so far. Maybe if differently handled? But I'm just a hobbyist. So there's that.